# Is the following statement about the probability measure true?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus

I'm thinking about the following statement.

> Let $(\Omega, F,\Bbb{P})$ be a discrete probability space. Is it true that if $$\Bbb{P}(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} sup~ A_n)=0$$then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Bbb{P}(A_n)<\infty$?

So I could show the other implication and now I'm thinking about a couterexample but I don't come up with one.

Could someone maybe help me where to start?

Comment: If $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence of non-negative numbers and $a_n\to 0$, is it true that  $\sum_n a_n <\infty$?

Comment: @Henry so sorry do you mean that there is a counterexample or not because if I read the answer below I understand it that it the statement is correct in our case

Comment: There are counter-examples to the question in my comment, and this is easily extended to a counter-example to the assertion in your question, most easily when the $a_n$ are decreasing towards $0$

Comment: so but doesn't John Dawkins says that it is true in our case?

Comment: Not in the second paragraph.  And there is an even more obvious counterexample

Comment: but there he assume that $\Omega$ is infinite. Do we know this in our case?

Answer (score 0):

If $\Bbb P(\limsup_{n\to\infty} A_n)=0$ then $K:=\sum_n1_{A_n}<\infty$ a.s. Because the probability space is discrete (which I understand to mean that $\Omega$ is countable and each singleton is measurable and has strictly positive weight) you must have $K(\omega)<\infty$ for *all* $\omega\in\Omega$. Notice that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Bbb P(A_n) =\Bbb E(K).
$$
And if $\Omega$ is *finite* then $\Bbb E(K)<\infty$. For a counterexample you therefore need $\Omega$ to be infinite. How about $\Omega=\{1,2,\ldots\}$ with $\Bbb P(\{k\})$ proportional to $k^{-2}$, and  $A_n=\{n,n+1,\ldots,2n\}$.